# How to represent data that can be multiple types

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have an array of objects where "value" can be different types, which I naively represent as:

```
interface Attribute {
  attribute: string;
  value: Date | string | string[];
}
```

```
[
    {
        attribute: 'date',
        value: new Date('2020-01-01')
    },
    {
        attribute: 'tags',
        value: ['foo', 'bar']
    }
    {
        attribute: 'name',
        value: 'Foo'
    }
]
```

I'm wondering if there is a better way to represent this data:

What "attributes" there are is dynamic, which is why they are represented as an array of objects that can have multiple value types.

I need to do different things with different types of values: e.g., if I encounter an object with a string array value, I need to be able to push strings to it. If I encounter an object with a date, I need to be able to display it in the right date format etc.

So I either need to use type guards or add a "type" property to each object and cast based on that:

```
{
    attribute: 'tags',
    value: ['foo', 'bar'],
    type: Type.StringArray
}
```

```
if (attribute.type === Type.StringArray) {
    return (attribute.value as string[]).join(', ');
}
```

Or I could perhaps represent things this way to avoid the need for casting:

```
{
    attribute: 'tags',
    stringArrayValue: ['foo', 'bar'],
    stringValue: undefined,
    dateValue: undefined
}
```

Are there better alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

```
interface TagsAttribute {
    attribute: 'tags';
    value: string[];
}

interface DateAttribute {
    attribute: 'date';
    value: Date;
}

interface NameAttribute {
    attribute: 'name';
    value: string;
}

type Attribute = TagAttribute | DateAttribute | NameAttribute;
```

`Attribute` type is called a discriminated union, `attribute` property is the discriminant.

Comment: The possible attributes is dynamic and unknown: there could be 'endDate', 'keywords' etc., and it's service-driven

Comment: So how would you dynamically define types for value properties?

Comment: The number of types would still be limited to a few known ones, but there could be new attributes; for example, `endDate` would still be of type `Date`

Comment: Well, that's fine. If the endDate tag will have a different behavior, just add another interface (interface EndDateAttribute) to the the union. If both endDate and date will behave the same, do this: `interface DateAttribute {
    attribute: 'date' | 'endDate';
    value: Date;
}`

Comment: The name of the attribute such as 'date' or 'endDate' can be any string, which I can't predict

Comment: So, again, how do you plan on mapping the attribute string to the value type? What's the value type of `attribute: 'abcd'`?

Comment: I think I would have to have a generic Attribute interface that could contain the attribute name and different types of values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214362/discussion-between-xli-and-ritaj).